# scope.$on() invokes several times for one broadcast

Tags: angularjs

In Angular.js, `scope.$on("UPDATE", function(event, account, vipLabel, nodeName)` is firing about 20 times when it should only invokes once for each `$rootScope.$broadcast("UPDATE", this.account,this.vipLabel, this.nodeName)`. I know that `scope.$on()` contains an event object, but I haven't been able to find a use for it to help my issue.

I am stuck on this and I need the `scope.$on()` to fire only once for each broadcast.

```
angular.module('main.vips')
.factory("StatusTrackerService", function($timeout, $rootScope, Restangular) {
    var CHECK_ITERATIONS = 1;
    var TIME_ITERATION = 1000;
    var eventCollection = {};
    eventCollection.vipLabel;

    function urlBuilder(account, eventId) {
        var account = Restangular.one("account", account);
        var eventId = account.one("event", eventId);
        return eventId;
    }

    function NewStatusEvent(account, eventId, url, vipLabel, nodeName) {
        this.iteration = 0;
        this.account = account;
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.url = url;
        this.vipLabel = vipLabel;
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    NewStatusEvent.prototype.runCheckLoop = function() {
        this.url.get()
        .then(function(data) {
            if (data.Automation.Status != "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("yes");
            console.log(this.iteration);
            console.log(CHECK_ITERATIONS);

                if (this.iteration < CHECK_ITERATIONS) {
                    this.iteration++;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("UPDATE", this.account,
                        this.vipLabel, this.nodeName);
                    console.log('-------------------');
                    console.log('checking ' + JSON.stringify(this.url));
                    console.log('iteration ' + this.iteration);
                    console.log('-------------------');
                    $timeout(function (){
                        this.runCheckLoop();
                    }.bind(this), TIME_ITERATION);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    function runEventCheck(account, eventId, nodeName) {
        url = urlBuilder(account, eventId);

        eventCollection[eventCollection.vipLabel] = new NewStatusEvent(account, eventId,
                url, eventCollection.vipLabel, nodeName);
        eventCollection[eventCollection.vipLabel].runCheckLoop();
    }
    return { runEventCheck: runEventCheck,
             eventCollection: eventCollection
    };
});
```

---

Directive:

```
            return {
                templateUrl: "vips/directives/action_button.html",
                restrict: "AE",
                replace: true,
                transclude: false,
                scope: {
                  label: "@?",
                  icon: "@?",
                  type: "@?",
                  actions: "=?"
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  element.on("click", function(event) {
                      var vipLabel = event.currentTarget.id;
                      StatusTrackerService.eventCollection.vipLabel = vipLabel;
                  });

                  scope.$on("UPDATE", function(event, account,
                              vipLabel, nodeName) {
                      console.log("Scope.on has fired this many times");
                      var nodeSelector = "#node-"+vipLabel+"-"+nodeName;
                      var nodeElement = angular.element(document.querySelector(nodeSelector));
                      if (!nodeElement.length) {
                          var vipElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#vipLabel-'+vipLabel));
                          var elementGlobe = '<div id="'+vipLabel+nodeName+'">Element modified</div>'; 
                          vipElement.append(elementGlobe);
                      }
                  });

                  return scope.actions = services[attrs.type];
                }
              }
});
```

---

Logged output:

```
21 -Scope.on has fired this many times actionButton.js:52
------------------- status-checker.js:35
checking {"id":"0fd6afd9-2367-4a0-a5c9-ff0b3e60cdcf","route":"event","reqParams":null,"$fromServer":false,"parentResource":{"route":"account","parentResource":null,"id":"99006"},"restangularCollection":false} status-checker.js:36
iteration 1 status-checker.js:37
-------------------
```

---

Html:

```
<div action-button type="loadbalancer" label="Actions" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"
       actions="actions.loadbalancer"></div>

</div>

              <div id="{{vip.label}}" action-button type="vip" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" actions="actions.vips"
                   class="pull-right"></div>


                      <div action-button type="node" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" actions="actions.nodes"
                           class="pull-right"></div>
```

**UPDATE**:
I added `if (scope.type !== "vip")` and it worked...now the event fires only once. It doesn't make sense to me because it is the `<div id="{{vip.label}}" action-button type="vip"` that I am using. It seems like it should be `if (scope.type == "vip")` instead...but it's the opposite.

```
          scope.$on("UPDATE", function(event, account,     
                      vipLabel, nodeName) {
              if (scope.type !== "vip") {
                console.log(scope);
              var nodeSelector = "#node-"+vipLabel+"-"+nodeName;
              var nodeElement = angular.element(document.querySelector(nodeSelector));
                console.log(nodeElement.length);
              if (nodeElement.length == 0) {
                  console.log("create node");
                  var vipElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#vipLabel-'+vipLabel));
                  var elementGlobe = '<div id="'+vipLabel+nodeName+'">Element modified</div>'; 
                  vipElement.append(elementGlobe);
              }
              }
          });
```

Comment: Since you have log outputs, can you add them here? Do you also receive the update evet 20 times when you register to it within an controller instead of a directive?

Comment: You seem to have already asked this question ;) ... Rather than Mark it as a duplicate, I'll ask you to clarify things a bit further.  Are you using this directive multiple times in your app and you only want one of the directives to process the event? Or perhaps does the HTML template for your directive create multiple scopes with ng-repeat or something similar? Try adding the relevant HTML to you question.

Comment: This post has been edited with the requested extra information

Comment: I'm assuming that we are talking about the `action-button` directive... If that's the case, then you have multiple instances of that directive in your HTML, which means each instance will receive a separate 'UPDATE' event.

Comment: That is fine at this point, but there are 3 instances and the `scope.$on()` is firing 21 times.

Comment: Do a test. 1) Add a log in the link function of the directive to know how many instances are being created. 2) Add a listener for `scope.$on('$destroy', function() { console.log("destroyed"); })` to know how many are being destroyed. 3) Compare the log counts...

Comment: Please see update on bottom. Why would this work?